# In javascript, how to add new rows in a table using document.createElement()?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to have a table and a textbox, when I input some value for the textbox then click the button, the value will be added into a table. I wrote the code but it doesn't run. Please help me to find out what wrong with the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script>
function send() {
        tbl=document.getElementById("idtable");
        tr = document.createElement("tr");
        td1 = document.createElement("td");
        td2 = document.createElement("td");
        name = document.getElementById("txtname").value;
        email = document.getElementById("txtemail").value;
        td1.innerText=name;
        td2.innerText=email;
        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        tbl.appendChild(tr);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txtname" name="txtname"/> <br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="txtemail" name="txtemail"/>
<p> <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="send()"/>
<table id="idtable" border="1">
<tr><td>Name</td> 
 <td>Email</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does browser JavaScript console say anything?

Comment: this code work fine what is he Problem ?

Comment: no, it doesn't!

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work on my computer.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work" ? What is wrong when running this code on your computer ?

Comment: When I click the send button, nothing happen. I've just send my friend this code, and it ran on her computer, so maybe the problem is not the code. I'll check my browser.

Comment: Try clear the browser's cache instead, then reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```js
function send(){
   var table=document.getElementById("table");
   name=document.getElementById("txtname").value;
   email=document.getElementById("txtemail").value;
   table.innerHTML+=('<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+email+'</td></tr>')
}
```

```html
<input id="txtname" name="txtname"/> <br/>
<input id="txtemail" name="txtemail"/> <br/>
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="send()"/><br/>
<table id="table" border="1">
   <tr><td>Name</td><td>Email</td></tr>
</table>
```